# Joomla - Displaying an article inside my component

Tags: joomla, components, joomla-article

I have a component for Joomla which I need to add an admin editable field to in order to display custom html.  This needs to be multi-lingual and my idea is to display and article in the component so that it is easily maintainable.

How would I do that without external plugins?  Or, what is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, if you want to avoid php-programming, would be to use [Joom!Fish](http://www.joomfish.net/). This way you will have full multi-lingual support.

Comment: I am using that, but the problem is that I need to add content to the page that the admin can update.  And I do not want to code PHP so I am trying to find an easy way of loading an article into my component.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to "Select Menu Item Type", Internal Link, Articles, Article, Article Submission Layout, which allows registered users to submit an Article through the front-end and also publish it if they have permissions?

Comment: Ok, I have now created a custom html component and translated it with Joomla, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The module however disappear after a postback even with ItemId in the URI.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you selected in the Publishing Area 1. Section, 2. Category, 3. Published Check, 4. Start Publishing date ?

Comment: Yes, it works if I navigate to the component using the menu, but not when I submit the form on the page...it just disappears :(

Comment: Ok, you live you learn.  I did not have my form's action as a JROUTE:: but hardcoded as a string instead, so Joomfish had no clue what I was looking at.  Thanks for the help!